# Electron with Pouchdb - unable to import leveldown

Tags: electron, pouchdb

A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
unable to import leveldown

```
Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
\\?\(Project Folder)\node_modules\leveldown\build\Release\leveldown.node: unable to import leveldown
at requireLeveldown ((Project Folder)\node_modules\pouchdb\lib\index.js:6206:12)
at PouchDB$5.LevelDownPouch ((Project Folder)\node_modules\pouchdb\lib\index.js:6406:17)
at new PouchDB$5 ((Project Folder)\node_modules\pouchdb\lib\index.js:2732:36)
at database_init ((Project Folder)\index.js:102:12)
at App.app.on ((Project Folder)\index.js:58:2)
at emitTwo (events.js:111:20)
at App.emit (events.js:191:7)
```

Comment: Maybe create a new issue on [Leveldown project](https://github.com/Level/leveldown/issues)

Comment: @Jeevan Did you get any solution to fix it?

Comment: use `electron-builder` and add this script `"postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"`, run it